# 仮想環境でvagrantが認識されない

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant, virtualbox

仮想環境の構築をしようとしていますが思った通りの動作をしないため一からやり直そうと思い、仮想マシンを削除(vagrant destroy)しようとしましたがvagrantが認識されていないようです。

これは仮想環境がそもそも出来ていなかったということなのでしょうか。また、ここから一からやり直すためにはどうしたらいいのでしょうか。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 1):

vagrant は仮想環境を構築する際のツールなので、基本はホストOS側で実行するコマンドです。
しかし画面ではプロンプトに vagrant と表示されているので、仮想環境の中 (ゲストOS) でコマンドを実行しているためにうまくいかないのだと思います。

Comment: ホストOS上で実行するにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。初歩的な質問ですみません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

詳細は違いますが、こんな感じで動作して、vagrant コマンドは必ずホストOS側で実行します。

[image: Vagrantの動作イメージ]

Comment: ホストOS側で実行するにはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。初歩的な質問で申し訳ございません。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: もしかして、vagrant up して同じコンソールでvagrant sshしてませんか？

Comment: 同じ質問をコピペして、別々のコメントって微妙ですよ。それぞれの人は、それぞれ時間を作って答えてくれているのに。vagrant のプロセス構成と仮想マシンの概念について理解されていますか？ほかの質問を見ても、そのあたりが不明のまま「使いたい」と思ってらっしゃるように見えます。

Comment: ご質問に点で答えます。上記のシーケンスにあるようにGuestOSからexitして、「ホストOSの」コンソール（ターミナル？コマンドプロンプト？）からvagrant haltするだけです。もしくは別のコンソール（以下略）を用意して、vagrant halt するでもよいです。この場合、お使いの環境のvagrantファイルがあるディレクトリに移動してからの実行になります。

Comment: あ、vagrant destroy したいのですね。この場合先ほどのvagrant haltをdestroyに読み替えてくださいね。

Answer (score 0):

> ここから一からやり直す

- Virtual Boxで該当のVMを停止する。
- VMをVirtual Boxの管理画面を使って削除する。
- vagrantファイルが存在するするディレクトリを削除する

で最初からやりなおせないですかね。
なんなら、今までのことを忘れてWindows再起動すれば、ゲストOSとまるので、あとはそんなこともあったなーと忘れてしまってもよいかもです。ディスクを圧迫しているだけなので、最初からやるには支障はないのではないかと思います。